# node.js package how to access other local files for audio

Tags: node.js, npm, package

I am trying to create my custom npm package.
It is all working except when I try to access another sound file within the same package.
**structure:**

```
sounds
    /soft_click_1s.wav
index.js
package.json
```

**index.js:**

```js
var audio = new Audio('/sounds/soft_click_1s.wav');
audio.play();
```

How do I create an Audio element and play it?

Comment: `Audio` works only in the browser

Comment: You have to expose the file to the browser

Comment: @Konrad Linkowski I see, is there a standard import/export method for this? or should I ask the users to run ```cp node_modules/packagename/sounds/soft_click_1s.wav public/sounds```?

Comment: You can try storing your audio as base64

Comment: @Konrad Linkowski Okay, thanks! I will try to look into base64 audios and keep the question updated.

Comment: You can try to find a library that is doing a similar thing and check how they are doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a bunch of things, and my final solution was the following:

##### sounds/sounds.js

```js
export const sound_click = "this_is_a_very_long_64_bit_sound_string"
```

##### index.js

```js
import {sound_click} from './sounds/sounds.js';

var audio = new Audio("data:audio/wav;base64," + sound_click);
audio.play();
```

This is probably not the cleanest of solutions, but it works just fine.
I am just piling up super long audio string inside a js file.

I also tries importing other dependencies, but had issues using them, and as my knowledge of node modules still lacks I could't comprehend much when looking at their github files.

If someone has a cleaner solution for this please share :)
Big thanks to Konrad for recommending base64 audio!